# tcpdf codeigniter getting error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to implement tcpdf library in codeigniter but getting error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Pdf in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\libraries\Pdf.php on line 6

here code example

path : "project\system\libraries\Pdf.php"

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }
}

/* End of file Pdf.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Pdf.php */
```

also Download latest 
[TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/)

also want to know which is best TCPDF or DOMPDF to generate quick PDF ?

Comment: I like tcpdf :)

Answer (score 0):

When using/making custom libraries, smart move would be (as CI makers advise too) to put it in `APPPATH.'libraries/'` because of upgrading version could overwrite/delete added files from `system` directory. That is why `application` folder is used for - to make any kind of custom files related to CI framework not touching default files/directories.

Other than that, error you've got there says there is more than one or better say there is two classes with same name. PHP doesn't allow that and every used file and/or class must have unique name. Possible solution should be renaming your file to

```
BASEPATH.'Pdf_lib.php'
```

and class name accordingly.

But again, if you are not limited with something else, move your class to

```
APPPATH.'libraries/Pdf_lib.php'
```

with following directories and subdirectories and files of `tcpdf` and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error using bellow method. its happen coz same class is call from other TCPDF included file here's the solution

path : "project\system\libraries\Pdf.php"

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once  '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

if (!class_exists('Pdf')) {
class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
}
```